# Embedded Applet Cannot Read File

Tags: java, applet, filereader

I imagine this would be a very rudimentary problem, since I am not quite familiar with applet deployments: I was made to convert a Swing application into an applet and embed it to a webpage. This applet constructs its knowledge base by reading lines from a text file (in the same directory as the .class file), and when I launched it from the applet viewer it reads the file with no problem.

Upon embedding, however, it fails to read the file and the exception handling is triggered. Perhaps this is one of those security restrictions?

I use File, FileReader, and LineNumberReader to read this document.

---

Additional problem: this also happens with images, where the applet would not run at all. I temporarily got around this by placing said images within an HTML file, but it could be done much better.

Comment: "I was made to convert a Swing application into an applet and embed it to a webpage."  Why?  Why not use [JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) to launch the application?  What does the web browser do for the applet?

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to load it directly using a file - use `Class.getResourceAsStream` and `InputStreamReader`. In other words, load it as a *resource* rather than as a file.

Comment: I tried to define the InputStream as `is = Class.forName("knowledgeBase.IO").getResourceAsStream("database.txt");`, but there appears to be an error when I tried to do `isr = new InputStreamReader(is);`. Is this a wrong approach?

Comment: `Class.forName("knowledgeBase.IO").getResourceAsStream("database.txt");` that is an unusual way to call the method.  Try `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("database.txt");`.  "..there appears to be an error"  What error?  I might guess, but I do not like guessing.

Comment: @Andrew: Where is your file in relation to the class? If it's at the root of the hierarchy, you might want `"/database.txt"` instead.

Comment: I got it covered. It was solved by simply changing the target to `"/database.txt"` like Jon mentioned.

Andrew, it's a bit unusual because it's a static method. I can't use `getClass()`.

Comment: @Bob: Don't use `Class.forName` when you know the class at compile time. Use `IO.class` or whatever.

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, sorry. Was in a rush to get out :)

Comment: Ah, all right. `IO.class` works just fine. I also used the `getResource` to use a URL object for the images and it worked just fine. Much obliged.